# How to combine two lists which removing duplicate from the second?

Tags: python

How do you combine two lists whilst ommitting items in the second list that have the same first tuple value as the first tuple value in the first list?

e.g 
If I have two lists:

```
a=[(1, 1), (2, 45), (7, 56), (32, 89)]
b=[(1, 34), (6, 89), (32, 75)]
```

The new list should be:

```
c=[(1, 1), (2, 45), (7, 56), (32, 89), (6, 89)]
```

without (1,34) or (32,75) since 1 and 32 are in the first list. The lists can be of any size.

Comment: Your attempt please?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov -- true but OP is only concerned about the first value if the tuple.

Comment: @FredrikPihl ok, missed that

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque - I was trying this code or similar to isolate the unique values in b without success: `[x for x,y in zip(b,a) if x[0]!=y[0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a set whith the first element of each tuple in `a` and use a list comprehension on the elements of `b`, discarding the tuples whose 1st element is contained in the set

```
>>> a=[(1, 1), (2, 45), (7, 56), (32, 89)]
>>> b=[(1, 34), (6, 89), (32, 75)]
>>> a+[j for j in b if j[0] not in {i[0] for i in a}]
[(1, 1), (2, 45), (7, 56), (32, 89), (6, 89)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to join you  list `a` to one for checking, then use list comprehension:

```
import itertools as it

full_a_list = list(it.chain(*a))
list_to_add = [i for i in b if i[0] not in full_a_list]
result = a + list_to_add

print(full_a_list)
[1, 1, 2, 45, 7, 56, 32, 89]

print(list_to_add)
[(6, 89)]

print(result)
[(1, 1), (2, 45), (7, 56), (32, 89), (6, 89)]
```

Comment: Whoa that's efficient, I like this.

Comment: Actually, I'll make a suggestion. Checking for membership in a list is inefficient with O(n) run time. However, if you use a hash `set()` it'll be much quicker: `list_to_add = [i for i in b if i[0] not in set(full_a_list)]`

Answer (score 1):

- Combine the lists: comb = a + b
- Sort them using a stable sort: comb.sort() (Luckily the sort in Python is stable)
- Walk through the sorted list and remove duplicates

Comment: @AhsanulHaque the sort is stable